# Convert Oracle function regexp_instr to Posgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I came across an Oracle function when converting Oracle 11g schema to Postgresql 11 as following:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT valid_session_time_zone CHECK (regexp_instr(trim(both session_time_zone),'(\+|\-|\s)?(0?[0-9]|1[01234])(:[0-5]\d)')=1);
```

So I translate that as a postgresql 11 DOMAIN

```
CREATE DOMAIN chk_time_zone AS VARCHAR CHECK ( VALUE ~* '(\+|\-|\s)?(0?[0-9]|1[01234])(:[0-5]\d)');
```

but how to trim both side of the string beforehand in my domain expression?

Comment: Adjust your regex to permit any number of whitespace before/after?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just my bad eyesight, but it looks the me that the original code has a problem. The original regexp requires that the matched string start with one of `+`, `-`, or blank, but the TRIM call would remove any leading blanks. Thus if the string to be matched starts with a blank which doesn't have a `+` or `-` after it, the TRIM call will remove the blank, and thus the pattern won't match. My recommendation is to just ignore the fact that the TRIM call is there, because it appears to be a potential bug, and proceed with the match as `~* '(\+|\-|\s)?(0?[0-9]|1[01234])(:[0-5]\d)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Oracle check doesn't manipulate the data entered into the table, it just checks that a trimmed version of it matches a pattern, so clearly it's OK to insert leading/trailing whitespace, or something elsewhere trims them off...

Thus I think you can ask PGSQL to disregard leading/trailing whitespace by permitting it in the pattern:

```
CREATE DOMAIN chk_time_zone AS VARCHAR CHECK 
( VALUE ~* '\s*(\+|\-|\s)?(0?[0-9]|1[01234])(:[0-5]\d)\s*');
```

Note that the regex as entered doesn't contain any anchors to the start or the end, so that pattern could occur anywhere in the data for a match. Add ^ at the start and $ at the end of the regex if the input must match the pattern entirely

For example: `'abcdef'` matches `'[cd]+'` but not `'^[cd]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

This is available out of the box in PostgreSQL 15 and later.

https://www.depesz.com/2021/11/26/waiting-for-postgresql-15-add-assorted-new-regexp_xxx-sql-functions/#more-4025

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP